# Query crashes MS Access

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, crm

**THE TASK:**
I am in the process of migrating a DB from MS Access to Maximizer. In order to do this I must take 64 tables in MS ACCESS and merge them into one. The output must be in the form of a TAB or CSV file. Which will then be imported into Maximizer.

**THE PROBLEM:**
Access is unable to perform a query that is so complex it seems, as it crashes any time I run the query.

**ALTERNATIVES:**
I have thought about a few alternatives, and would like to do the least time-consuming one, out of these, while also taking advantage of any opportunities to learn something new.

1. Export each table into CSVs and import into SQLight and then make a query with it to do the same as what ACCESS fails to do (merge 64 tables).
2. Export each table into CSVs and write a script to access each one and merge the CSVs into a single CSV.
3. Somehow connect to the MS ACCESS DB (API), and write a script to pull data from each table and merge them into a CSV file.

**QUESTION:**
What do you recommend?

**CLARIFICATIONS:**

1. I am merging tables, not concatenating. Each table has a different structure and different data. It is a normalized CRM database. Companies->contacts->details = ~ 60 tables of details.
2. As the Access db will be scuttled after the db is migrated, I want to spend as little time in Access as possible.

Comment: can you give the structure (overview) and query?

Comment: another possibility might be to figure out what is wrong technically, change it in the MS Access DB, and then run the query without crashing the database.  Perhaps it is merely a question of insufficient memory, insufficient indices, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with FrustratedWithFormsDesigner. #2 seems the simplest method.

Here is some tested code if you decide to go that route (requires [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc)):

```
import csv
import pyodbc

MDB = 'c:/path/to/my.mdb'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
PWD = 'mypassword'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
curs = conn.cursor()

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM mytable;' # insert your query here
curs.execute(SQL)

rows = curs.fetchall()

curs.close()
conn.close()

# you could change the 'w' to 'a' for subsequent queries
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('mytable.csv', 'w'), lineterminator='\n')

for row in rows:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to merge 64 tables, may we assume those tables all have the same structure?

If so, create a new empty table with matching structure, then append the rows from each of those 64 tables into the new merge master table.  Then export the merge master table as a single CSV file.

The merge operation should not have to be a single complex query.

```
INSERT INTO tblMergeMaster(
    some_field,
    another_field,
    yet_another)
SELECT
    some_field,
    another_field,
    yet_another
FROM
    tbl_1_of_64;
```

You can build the INSERT statement 64 times with VBA code, with a different FROM table each time.  And execute each statement with CurrentDb.Execute

Comment: Ahh.  I didn't want to assume that the tables had the same format.  Since the OP used "merge" instead of "concatenate" or "combine", I figured that there was some joining involved.  Good answer is that is a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend #2 if the merge is fairly simple and straightforward, and doesn't need the power of an RDBMS. I'd go with #1 if the merge is more complex and you will need to write some actual queries to get the data merged properly.

Comment: You can easily merge CSV files from the command prompt COPY x + y z

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even clear on what you're trying to do. I assume your problem is that Jet/ACE can't handle a UNION with that many SELECT statements.

If you have 64 identically-structured tables and you want them in a single CSV, I'd create a temp table in Access, append each table in turn, then export from the temp table to CSV. This is a simple solution and shouldn't be slow, either. The only possible issue might be if there are dupes, but if there are, you can export from a SELECT DISTINCT saved QueryDef.

Tangentially, I'm surprised Maximizer still exists. I had a client who used to use it, and the db structure was terribly unnormalized, just like all the other sales software like ACT.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Maximizer, but what you say does sound like what I think the OP is trying to do: merge ~60 normalized tables into one gigantic de-normalized table. An extraordinarily bad idea IMHO. Even with my low opinion of MS Access, this *Maximizer* sounds even worse.