# How do I create a .MDB and import a CSV into it using Python

Tags: python, ms-access, csv

Does anyone have any examples of creating a new Access Database and importing a CSV file (only specific fields) into the database?

Thanks

Comment: There's a post that does the opposite (read mdb and write it to CSV), but hopefully it can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea and a link for further info:

I have not tested the following for creating a new mdb so ymmv!

```
import win32com.client
eng=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("DAO.DBEngine.36")
eng.CreateDatabase("c:\\myNewAccessdB.mdb", win32com.client.constants.dbLangGeneral)
```

Here is a [link](http://www.ecp.cc/pyado.html) to some good info for working with python and ado.

I hope this helps.

~M

Sorry I do not have any examples for working the csv into the empty mdb :( If I come with anything I will post later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyPyODBC to do this.

To create an Access mdb file:

```
import pypyodbc
pypyodbc.win_create_mdb( "D:\\Your MDB file path.mdb" )
```

If you want, you can continue to use pypyodbc to connect to the creatmdb files and manipulate them with ODBC interface similar to pyodbc:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect(u'''Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='''+mdb_path
                    , unicode_results = True
                    , readonly = False)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute ('Drop table pypyodbc_test_tabl')
cur.execdirect(u"""create table pypyodbc_test_tabl (ID integer PRIMARY KEY,product_name text)""")

...
cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Finally, To compact an existing Access mdb file

```
pypyodbc.win_compact_mdb("D:\\The path to the original to be compacted mdb file"
                   ,"D:\\The path to put the compacted new mdb file")
```