# converting .mdb file into numpy or hdf5

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, mdbtools, lmdb

Is there any API in python that can load .mdb file in linux environment and convert them into python friendly data structure like numpy or hdf5?

Comment: I think this url will help you.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python

Comment: Tried with this, but this thread does not deal with linux environment.

Comment: I'm seeing lots of references to `mdbtools`, and some `py` packages to access that.

Comment: Also look into `csv` export and conversion to other databases (e.g. `mysql`).  Transforming your data into `numpy` arrays (and storing them in `hd5f` format) is a step beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is an open-source Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb).

There is the  [Easysoft MDB Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/#section=tab-1) (time limited free evaluation license)  which is compatible with unixODBC that you can then use from python with `pyodbc` (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python), mentionned in the comments by @ljdawn ).

Here is a detailed [guide](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/pyodbc.html) that explains how to make this work.