# Import a .mdb file into Python

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc, jupyter-console

I want to import a .mdb file into Python (I'm using Jupyter). My file name is PIF.mdb and i want a table called ValuesXYZ. Do anyone know what code works for this? I teste a lot of codes but they doesn't worked.
So grateful,
Henrique.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **cannot** directly read the table.
.mdb is database file and not tables. You need to connect to it first, via pyodbc for example.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python) explains it really well.