# Using an Access database (.mdb) with Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ms-access, ubuntu, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to access a .mdb on Ubuntu. I've based my progress so far on this link

[Query crashes MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064830/query-crashes-ms-access)

I have installed pyodbc, unixodbc, and unixodbc-dev

My code looks like this:

```
import csv
import pyodbc

MDB = 'URY.mdb'
DRV ='Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)'
PWD = 'pass'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
curs = conn.cursor()
```

When I run it, I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mdbscraper.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found,         and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be very much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linux, but on Windows, this error would mean that you did not set up an ODBC connection in Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC Connections. And you'd pass the Data Source Name (DNS) in the connection, not the name of file (that's in the DNS).

Comment: I think because I'm using a .mdb it's all local, so I don't need a DNS. Does that sound right? I'm basing it on the example at the top of this page https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings

Comment: I think you still need to install an ODBC driver for MS Access.  Easysoft sells one. http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html  Supposedly mdbtools includes one but it's described as limited.  http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/install/x90.htm

Comment: Thank you. I found the necessary driver on their website as a tar. Do you know where I need to put it?

Comment: I never tried it.  See their getting started guide. http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/getting-started.html

Comment: I am facing the same error. @mythhander889 how did you fix this? Please share.

Comment: @fakhirhanif unfortunately, I never got it working. I found a command line utility that did something similar, then wrote a small bash script to dump it out to a csv

Comment: @mythander889, Now i am able to connect with .mdb file using pyodbc. It is crashing when i fetch records after executing the query.

Answer (score 5):

From what I know this driver "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)" is only available on a Microsoft host, since you are on ubuntu, it won't work.

Comment: Yes I am with this answer so far. Please share if someone has the solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
import pyodbc 
DBfile = '/data/MSAccess/Music_Library.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
cursor = conn.cursor()
SQL = 'SELECT Artist, AlbumName FROM RecordCollection ORDER BY Year;'

for row in cursor.execute(SQL): # cursors are iterable
print row.Artist, row.AlbumName

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

There is The Official Example .. of use ...