# How to read .mdb access database file in python?

Tags: python, azure, ms-access, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I need to read the .mdb file in python which is in azure blob storage and export dataframe as as csv, I am able to read the csv but i am not able to read the .mdb file. Is there any other method to do so, Please feel free to give suggestion other than python.

What i tried:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
import pandas as pd
import tables

STORAGEACCOUNTNAME= <storage_account_name>
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= <storage_account_key>
LOCALFILENAME= <local_file_name>
CONTAINERNAME= <container_name>
BLOBNAME= <blob_name>

blob_service=BlockBlobService(account_name=STORAGEACCOUNTNAME,account_key=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINERNAME,BLOBNAME,test.mdb)

# LOCALFILE is the file path
dataframe_blobdata = pd.read_csv(test.mdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to install [mdbtools](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools) (`brew install mdbtools` on MacOS) use them to convert the database to a sqlite database, which is much easier to use from Python via `import sqlite3` -- and you won't run into the problem of trying to use `pyodbc` and realizing you don't have an MDB driver and then trying to go find one, pay for it, install it, and use it.

I had this problem and wrote a small script to wrap mdbtools and convert the mdb  database to sqlite. The important piece is below:

```py
def list_tables(filename):
    delimiter = ", "
    u = run_command(["mdb-tables", "-d", delimiter, filename])
    tables = u.split(delimiter)
    return [stripped for t in tables if (stripped := t.strip()) != ""]

def export_sqlite(dbname, tablenames, filename):
    print(f"creating {filename}")
    con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cur = con.cursor()

    # Populate it.
    create = "mdb-schema --indexes --relations --default-values --not-null".split(" ")
    for table in tablenames:
        print(f"creating table {table}")
        table_create = run_command(create + [dbname, "-T", table, "sqlite"])
        cur.execute(table_create)

        sql = run_command(["mdb-export", "-I", "sqlite", "-S", "1", dbname, table])
        for i, ins in enumerate(sql.split(";\n")):
            cur.execute(ins)

        print(f"inserted {i} records into {table}")
        con.commit()
    con.close()

def main(filename):
    tables = list_tables(filename)
    export_sqlite(filename, tables, filename + '.sqlite')
```

Sharing the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/jsundram/f362c5a62e0dc9cb1aab9c815d9e5b5c) in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To read .mdb files from database it requires third party application called [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc#pyodbc) and below is the sample code for reading .mdb files from python.

```sql
import csv
import pyodbc

MDB = 'c:/path/to/my.mdb'
DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
PWD = 'mypassword'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=%s;DBQ=%s;PWD=%s' % (DRV,MDB,PWD))
curs = conn.cursor()

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM mytable;' # insert your query here
curs.execute(SQL)

rows = curs.fetchall()

curs.close()
conn.close()

# you could change the 'w' to 'a' for subsequent queries
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('mytable.csv', 'w'), lineterminator='\n')

for row in rows:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

For further information find the related [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3064986) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14288541)

Comment: I think the windows dependencies won't work on azure env since it is using linux env

Comment: if at all it is linux env try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15400363